# UINavigationController in Watchkit

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, apple-watch, watchos-6

Is there a way to control the navigation bar in WatchOS similar to how we can control it in iOS using UINavigationController?

What I am trying to do is hide the navigation bar for certain WKInterfaceControllers and show it for others. What I am able to do so far is hiding the navigation bar for the entire WatchOS app.

Answer (score 1):

What do you exactly mean by hiding `NavigationBar` for `WKInterfaceController`?

As we know in Apple Watch, there are **two** ways to navigate between Interface Controllers:

- **Hierarchical** (adding scenes to the stack)

Pushes another Interface Controller on the screen

- **Page-based** (presenting scenes modally)

Displays another Interface Controller on top of the current Interface Controller.

The [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/elements/navigation-bar/) says that

> The navigation bar appears at the top edge of the Apple Watch screen. The system displays **the clock** at one end of the navigation bar and provides **a title area** at the opposite end. The **title area** can also include navigational elements such as a `Back Button` or a `Dismiss Button`.

> **IMPORTANT**: The clock appears in the navigation bar **of every nonmodal** app screen.
> You **can’t remove** the clock, so be sure to account for it in your
> designs.

I wrote this to came to the conclusion that you want to remove the `Back Button`, correct?
If so, you may try this:

```
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: ["DestinationInterfaceController"], contexts: nil, orientation: .horizontal, pageIndex: 0)
```

In the `DestinationInterfaceController`, you should put the identifier of the destination Interface Controller.

Comment: The answer to your first question: I would like to hide the navigation bar and show only the clock. This can be accomplished by checking the "Full screen" option in the storyboard. As a result, my concern is not to hide the "Back button".

Moreover, there are two options in "Info.plist" to hide/show the status (navigation) bar without using the storyboard. "View controller-based status bar appearance" and "status bar is initially hidden". However, the caveat with this is that you can hide/show the status bar for the entire app, not separate controllers as I intend.